# Best stack site for this question

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which is the best stack site to ask this question:

Which is the good yet economical (or free) OCR SDK tool to convert Arabic text from scanned card images?

Comment: Maybe [softwarerecs.se]?

Comment: Only there.  Nowhere else.

Comment: Would need more detail than what you've provided in order to be acceptable at Software Recommendations. Make sure you look around there and read the help center before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this form the question shouldn't be asked anywhere in the Stack Exchange network because the question is broad, asking for opinions and a [plain shopping question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

If you visit [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) you'll find this text on their [on-topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page:

> Good software recommendation requests have two components:

- A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story
- Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features

Beyond this they have a post with [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) that require you to post the correct content in the correct format.

On content expect to provide at least: the kind of application you're looking for; the operating system to be used; your budget; needs and features of the application

For formatting you have to make sure that your post has a clear title and it's features should be listed in order of importance.

If you are able to improve the question into a post that meets above standards you could consider asking at SR. Before you do, search their site, you might find an answer there. When still in doubt if your improved question is OK ask on their [meta first](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).